# Python - spaces

Tags: python, printing, spaces

I can't get over this little problem.

[image]

The second is right.

How can i print without spaces?

```
def square(n):
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            if i==0 or j==0 or i==n-1 or j==n-1: print "*",
            else: print "+",
    print
```

thanks for help!

Comment: I would build the whole line as a string before printing it. Or use Python 3, where you can set the "end" to `''`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By not using `print` plus a comma; the comma will insert a space instead of a newline in this case.

Use `sys.stdout.write()` to get more control:

```
import sys

def square(n):
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            if i==0 or j==0 or i==n-1 or j==n-1: sys.stdout.write("*")
            else: sys.stdout.write("+")
        print
```

`print` just writes to `sys.stdout` for you, albeit that it also handles multiple arguments, converts values to strings first and adds a newline unless you end the expression with a comma.

You could also use the Python 3 [`print()` *function*](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#print) in Python 2 and ask it not to print a newline:

```
from __future__ import print_function

def square(n):
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            if i==0 or j==0 or i==n-1 or j==n-1: print("*", end='')
            else: print("+", end='')
        print()
```

Alternatively, join the strings first with `''.join()`:

```
def square(n):
    for i in range(n):
        print ''.join(['*' if i in (0, n-1) or j in (0, n-1) else '+' for j in xrange(n)])
```

Comment: We can remove `[` `]` in Join and add `(` `)` for print function call for Python 3...

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/9061024; for a `''.join()` call it is *faster* to use a list comprehension instead of a generator expression.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try to use `sys.stdout.write("+")` instead of `print "+"` ?

Answer (score 0):

In [python 3](http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/functions.html#print) you can overwrite the print behaviour, here *this* will solve your problem:

```
print("+", end="")
```

Comment: Not in Python 2, where `print` is a *statement*, not a function. Unless you tell the Python compiler you wanted to use the function instead (by using `from __future__ import print_function`).